# how to extract datetime from JSON file?

Tags: arrays, json, datetime, extract, java-time

I have powerBI performance data exported as a JSON. I want to get elapsed time at each step and overall. I have a 3,700 line JSON with data in roughly this format, what would be the easiest way to extract datetime/measure elapsed time?

```
{
        "name": "Resolve Parameters",
        "component": "Report Canvas",
        "start": "2024-03-01T22:36:49.447Z",
        "end": "2024-03-01T22:36:49.454Z",
        "id": "81d8a863c3d6068b0a82",
        "parentId": "497f9a56808028024c13-9a3fc7adb48ad65ac7cc"
    },
```

I tried reading this file into excel as a JSON and it doesn't properly read in all of the sub files. I have vague experience in python/C++, but very rusty. Tutorials welcome.

Comment: Your search engine can find the tutorials. A JSON library can convert your JSON file. And your search engine can find those libraries too.